# How can I reduce 8 different values into 4 via pandas? It is a categorical variable and each value represents a level of education

Tags: pandas

Basically if X025==1, X025==2 I want my variable to be 1, when X025==3, X025==4, X025==5, X025==6 I want it to be 2, 3 when  X025==7, X025==8 and 4  when it is X025<1

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like that:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def assignGroup(row):
    if row['X025'] in [1,2]:
        return 1
    elif row['X025'] in [3,4,5,6]:
        return 2
    elif row['X025'] in [7,8]:
        return 3
    elif row['X025'] in [-1]:
        return 4
    else:
        return np.nan

    
        

data = np.random.randint(-1,8,size=10)
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['X025'])

df['group']=df.apply(assignGroup,axis=1)

print (df)
```

Result:

```
   X025  group
0     1    1.0
1    -1    4.0
2     6    2.0
3     0    NaN
4     1    1.0
5    -1    4.0
6     1    1.0
7     1    1.0
8     5    2.0
9     1    1.0
```

Comment: I was exactly looking for this code. Many thanks!